# Firebase + RecyclerView: notifyItemRemoved not working properly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am able to delete my entries from the Firebase storage and database, but when I call notifyItemRemoved, it's not working properly. It isn't deleting the entry and I think this is because its interferring with the ValueEventListener which is also triggered on the update. When I leave the activity and reopen it, the entries are (correctly) gone.

Can anyone suggest me what I have to change in my activity for this to work properly?

```
public class ImagesActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ImageAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ImageAdapter mAdapter;

private ProgressBar mProgressCircle;

private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
private List<Upload> mUploads;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_images);

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    mProgressCircle = findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);

    mUploads = new ArrayList<>();

    mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {               
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {  
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);        
                upload.setKey(postSnapshot.getKey());
                mUploads.add(upload);
            }

            mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImagesActivity.this, mUploads);

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ImagesActivity.this);

            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ImagesActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
    Upload selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
    final String selectedKey = selectedItem.getKey();

    StorageReference imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getImageUrl());
    imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            mDatabaseRef.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
        }
    });

    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you try remove `item` from `List` first then notify adapter that item is removed? Like: `mUploads.remove(position);`

Comment: Ah of course! You are right, it is still in the ArrayList. Thank you for that! However, I don't have an animation now because the ValueEventListener is triggered as well. I will have to figure out how to change that. Or I just skip the adapter notify method completely and let the ValueEventListener update the list. Do you think it is bad to create a new adapter every time the ValueEventListener is triggered?

Comment: Yes because `List` is populated with data. I will post an answer. Yes it is bad because of that we have `notifyDataSetChanged()` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Because your `List` is populated with data and no matter if you remove data from database it is still inside the `List`. So you need first to remove data from `List` and then notify adapter that data is removed. For example:

`mUploads.remove(position);
 mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);`

To play animation after deleting try to use:

`notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());`

Consider removing the adapter class from `onDataChange` to prevent recreating the adapter again and again. Also in future when working with the `Firebase` database and `RecyclerView` consider using: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

Comment: The problem is that the ValueEventListener gets triggered every time the data in the database changes, so when I call notifyItemRemoved it will immediatly trigger the ValueEventListener is well where I either set a new adapter or call notifyDataSetChanged. Don't really know how to get around this.

Comment: You will remove data from adapter and `List` when you remove it from database so maybe is better to you to move those lines of code inside `onSucces` because you want to be sure that data is removed from database first.

Comment: The ValueEventListener gets triggered automatically every time something in the database changes

Comment: Yes so what scenario you get when perform deleting?

Comment: Well actually the animation works (probably because there is a short delay before the ValueEventListener is called) but it randomly adds new items to the bottom of the RecyclerView and I don't know why.

Comment: Try to move those lines of code:  `mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(ImagesActivity.this, mUploads);

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ImagesActivity.this);

            mProgressCircle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`
form `addValueListener` and put it below or at least remove setting the adapter to `recyclerView` because every time you are setting new `adapter`

Comment: Yea you are right I should put that somewhere else and I actually did that already. But it doesn't really change the problem because I have to atleast call notifyDataSetChanged in the ValueEventListener which pretty much behaves the same as setting a new adapter (I mean in terms of updating the list). I don't know where my bug is coming from.

Comment: It does not behaves like adding new adapter if you call it outside of `for` loop. It works like refreshing the adapter but seems you have bug somewhere else also.

Comment: Yea, the bug must be somewhere else but this is beyond the scope of this question. So I thank you for giving me your time!